# How to pass json list values into python list?

Tags: python, json

My json data will print all the items of my emailList when I do this:

```
        print(data['emailList'])
```

and it will return this:

```
[
{
'emailId': 987654321,
'customerId': 123456789,
},
{
'emailId': 56789,
'customerId': 8765,
}
]
```

How could I include all the possible values for customerId into my final_list? I've tried this:

```
 final_list = []
    for each_requ in data:
        final_list.append(each_requ)[emailList][customerId]
    return final_list
```

but received this error:

```
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

desired output:

```
    [123456789 ,8765]
```

Comment: `print(data['emailList'][customerId])` won't print anything.

Comment: Your "json data" are plain ordinary Python types - in your case a python dict which "emailList" key points to a python list of python dicts. IOW, the fact you got those data from json is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here the solution

```
your_json = [{'emailId': 987654321, 'customerId': 123456789},
 {'emailId': 56789, 'customerId': 8765}]

[i['customerId'] for i in your_json]  
[123456789, 8765]
```

so for your code, you can do something like that

```
email_list = data['emailList']
result = [i['customerId'] for i in email_list]
```

or single line

```
result = [i['customerId'] for i in data['emailList']]
```

with map

```
result = list(map(lambda x: x['customerId'], data['emailList']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final_list = []
    for each_requ in data:
        final_list.append(each_requ['customerId'])
    return final_list
```

this should return your desired results if json like dict is in `data` variable